# Access Block Document

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, ethereumjs

I have a requirement where we need to save data(pdf) to blockchain so that any third party can access and view it later by the block address. I can't store the hash of the data on blockchain as the third party does not have access to the original document to verify the hash of the data. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1):

No. Storing documents to Ethereum blockchain is not feasible due to the excessive gas requirements - it would either cost you way too much or it wouldn't be possible at all due to gas limits.

You should use some other blockchains which are meant for data (file) storage such as FileCoin or StorJ.